# Compositing why is mask displaying white when subtracting from an image sequence

Tags: compositing-nodes

Why is this mask displaying white/grey, I suspect it's something to do with the mix node? The highlighted mask is doing its job by subtracting from the shutter image sequence but when I set the mix value to 0.005 as per the rest of the mix nodes in the comp it is still visible as a white mask as per the mask shape. You can also see this around the LH window frame on the side nearest to the camera.

I have this in other areas of the comp whereby if I leave a mask within the working area it leaves a cutout out of the rest of the comp but leaving a darker patch on the footage.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Convert premultiplied needs to be checked in the alpha over node so it interprets the alpha channel properly, this sorted it. Might be useful for someone else.